# é is a tab? What encoding error might cause this?

Tags: character-encoding

This only seems to happen in Chrome, but when AJAX is used to send a JSON-encoded string containing `é` (which itself is typed by entering `Alt+0233`), it somehow ends up as a tab (character 9) in the database and "consumes" the following character.

I'm no stranger to Ã© being shown instead of é because that's the UTF8-encoded "version" being treated as iso-8559-1, but what could cause `0b11101001` to become `0b00001001`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have not found the reason for the encoding error, I have managed to fix the issue by checking the character encoding of the sent data and re-encoding as necessary.